# Function like template parametrs

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone explain me, how to write template parameters like in `boost::function` (for example `boost::function<int (float,bool)>` ). What is a right syntax?

I try this:

```
template <typename T (typename Arg1,typename Arg2)>
struct func{};
```

but it doesn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct func {};
```

`int (float, bool)` itself is already a type.

---

If you *only* want to match types being a function with 2 parameters, create a specialization like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct func;

template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2>
struct func<R(T1,T2)> {
   typedef R return_type;
   typedef T1 first_argument_type;
   typedef T2 second_argument_type;
};
```

Comment: Wait, how? And why? Maybe I'm missing something basic, but please explain!

Comment: @KennyTM And how can I use such construction? For example how to  declare variable in struct which  type is function's returning type?

Comment: @Xeo `int (float, bool)` is a type of function, which returns int and have 2 arguments: float and bool. So we can use it as type argument in template declaration.

Comment: @Ashot: Thanks. I always wondered how `boost::function` works, and now I at least understand why such template arguments work at all! :)